# Custom Translator - Can't deploy more than 1 model (Model Action does not appear)

Tags: microsoft-translator

I have successfully created training with status = "Training succeeded" but not appear Model Action button to deploy/update.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhiRh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one model deployed per project. To deploy this new model, you need to undeploy the one at the top that shows 'update'. If you want to have both deployed, they need to be in separate projects.